# How does the flaw limited magic resistance work?

Tags: ars-magica-5

Limited Magic Resistance states:

> You are less able to resist magic than other
>   magi. You gain no bonus from one of your Form
>   scores to Magic Resistance rolls, though if you
>   are caught without your Parma Magica, you
>   retain a Magic Resistance of 0. You may take this
>   Flaw multiple times, for multiple Forms.

When does a magi actually *roll* for magic resistance? In what situations is this applicable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The passage you cited makes no mention of rolling, only that the magus with Limited Magic Resistance has a Form which does not increase his Magic Resistance against relevant spells.

Per ArM5, p. 85:

> Hermetic magi have a base Magic Resistance equal to their score in the
>   Form most applicable to the spell cast.

Further down the same page:

> The Parma Magica, Bonisagus’s great invention, is an Ability that
>   grants magic resistance that adds to the resistance arising from a
>   maga’s Form scores.

Therefore, a magus with Limited Magic Resistance will have Magic Resistance of only `(Parma Magica * 5)` against one Form's spells rather than the normal `(Parma Magica * 5) + Form`.